# D7 indexing page

Tags: taxonomy-terms, navigation

I am looking to create a dropdown menu that will display all the tags but in a indexing manner. See example at http://www.healthinfonet.ecu.edu.au for the A-Z topic menu.

Anyway we can do that in D7 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a view which is displaying the list and connect that to the menu with the help of module. https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views

Comment: Hi Justme, shall I create a view of Block or Page ?

Comment: I did it with a block